# Confusion from Boundary conditions in Dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, boundary-conditions, dielectric

[image]

As for (a), I easily derived that $\mathbf {E}_2 = \mathbf E_1$ at the 'boundary' of the intersection plane. However, how do I know the rest of the second region? The solution states rest of the region is also same as the one derived at the 'boundary', but I don't understand the exact logic.

Comment: Try it. Does $\mathbf E_2=\mathbf E_1$ satisfy Maxwell's equations and the boundary conditions? If it does, that's your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to consider how this can be a solution of Maxwell's equations. The only one you really need to worry about is:

$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{D}=\eta
$$

Where $\eta$ is the charge density. You can integrate both sides of this equation over the volume of a cylinder with the axis of symmetry that is aligned with your coordinates, and with radius such that it cuts into your dielectric wedges. The symmetry of your problem along the z-axis suggests that $\mathbf{E}$ and therefore $\mathbf{D}=\epsilon_0\epsilon_r \mathbf{E}$ will not have z-axis component. One solution you could aim for is $D_\rho=\eta'/2\pi\rho$, $\mathbf{D}=\boldsymbol{\hat{\rho}}D_\rho \:\forall\rho\neq0$. Here $\eta'$ is the charge density per length of the cylindrical volume you chose to integrate.

It is easy to check that such solution implies that there is no charge density present anywhere where $\rho\neq 0$, which should be fine for you. The behavior at $\rho=0$, would need special handling. I recon $D_\rho=\eta' H\left(2\rho\right)/2\pi\rho$ is the correct expression, where $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), but it is probably not terribly important.

Going back to your exercise, you should now be able to work out the fields in all dielectrics as long as you know one of them - simply keep the displacement $\mathbf{D}$ the same function of the radius